# How to create a custom Sonar rule to check if a method throws a certain exception?

Tags: sonarqube

So we want to check a certain method, say findOne() in certain java classes if it throws a specific exception or not. If it doesn't throw the exception, then an issue to be reported at method level.

We could use

```
public void visitThrowStatement(ThrowStatementTree tree)
```

but this only gets called when there is a statement that throws the exception, how can we check if it's not thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a context in your visitor to know in which method you are currently visiting throw statements.

Basically, if you are within a `findOne` method, then you will visit the code of the method, if it has a correct throw statement,then don't raise an issue but if it has not then raise an issue.

Something along the lines of (this is pseudo code and should of course be adapted but that will explain the concept):

```
LinkedList<MethodTree> stack;
int throwCount = 0;
void visitMethod(MethodTree methodTree) {
   stack.push(methodTree);
   throwCount = 0;
   super.visitMethod(methodTree);
   if(throwCount == 0) {
      //raise Issue
   }
}

void visit throwStatement(ThrowStatementTree tree) {
   if(isCorrectExceptionThrown(tree)) {
     throwCount++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what's the reason you push methodTree into stack?

Comment: well that's to keep a context of what's going on. You might have local classes that defines methods  : 

` void foo() { class A { void bar() {throw new myException()}};}`